# Check if function in external js is available before calling onclick function

Tags: javascript, callback

We load a third party script asynchronously through https://athirdpartysite.com/lib.js.  The third party script includes a function, FSFB.fbcaller('123abc') that we want to invoke when a user clicks on an element, . We generate #invoker using innerHTML. How can I ensure that the function FSFB.fbcaller('123abc') is available before attaching the onclick event to #invoker?

```
window.onload = function () {
    function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
        referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode,
    referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

ar el = document.createElement("div");
el.id = "invoker-container";
el.innerHTML = '<ul><li></li><li><div id="invoker"></div></li></ul>';  
var afterel = document.querySelector(".master-container");
insertAfter(afterel, el);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting errors? If so, what errors?

Comment: Using the answer with type of check is the best since it doesn't throw errors if undefined and it makes sure the target is in fact a function not a variable

Comment: @MaherFattouh Uh? Neither answer will throw errors on undefined. *"a function not a variable"* -- variables and functions are orthogonal concepts. Variables can hold functions.

Comment: I just tested your code, using `window.FSFB` instead of `FSFB` you're right it does not throw an error. usually I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: FSFB is not defined`. and by the 2nd issue I meant a non-function object but yes technically you're right on that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test using this conditional:

```
if (window.FSFB && window.FSFB.fbcaller) {
    // Function is available
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(typeof FSFB == "function"){
  if(typeof FSFB.fbcaller == "function"){
    //function exist
  }
}
```

this should work

Comment: How do you know that `FSFB` is a function? it could be an object, in that case your code wouldn't work as expected

Comment: FSFB is a global function like the jQuery.ajax for example the jQuery is the global function  and ajax  is the function i want to call and the same thing goes for FSFB.fbcaller you check the global function first if it exist you move to the desired function if it is an object you want get inside the if condition

Comment: check this out http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/operators/typeof.php